# php mx lookup and if then else

Tags: php

I Try to made a - as I thinked - easy Script, which simply checks the MX Record of a Mail address and if it Matches, redirect to an specific URL.

Suddenly... I have no clue how to work it out. I found some things on google, but it seems not to work. Where is my Fault?

```
    <title>Mailredirector</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- ********** HEADER START ********** -->
  <hr>         
  <br>
  <!-- ********** HEADER ENDE ********** -->
  <!-- ********** FORMULAR START ********** -->
  <form method="post" action="mxnew.php">
   <p style="text-align: center">
    Bitte geben sie Ihre Mailadresse ein und klicken sie auf Senden<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Email:&nbsp;</b><input type="email" name="email" id="email" style="height: 30px; width: 350px;"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Check" id="dsubmit" name ="submit" style="width: 80px; height: 30px;"/>
   </p>
  </form>
  <!-- ********** FORMULAR ENDE ********** -->
  <!-- ********** FOOTER START ********** -->
  <hr>
  <!-- ********** FOOTER ENDE ********** -->
 </body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
/* <----- Domain von Name trennen ----->*/
$domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
/* <----- MX Record und Domain prüfen ----->*/
function mxrecordValidate($email, $domain) {
$arr = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
return $arr[0]['target'];
}
/* <----- Weiterleitungen an andere Domain ----->*/
if ($arr['target'] == mx.domain.com) {
    Header ('location: http://google.ch');
    die();
}
if ($arr['target'] == all01.mx.domain.ch) {
    Header ('location: http://google.fr');
    die();
}
else {
    Header ('location: http://google.com');
    die();
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is it doing that you do not expect or want? Please be specific about how it is broken to get the best answers possible :)

Comment: Thank you for the Response... the thing is: It should redirect, if a MX Lookup matches, but it... does nothing. Or nothing viewable.

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete: you never call `mxrecordValidate()`. So it can't obviously do anything. In addition, I'm not sure of the effect of `die` after redirections: might merely stop all (so redirection doesn't happen). The common way is to `exit` instead.

Comment: Thank you cFreed - i will try that and made an update after trying.

Comment: I have to say... i have absolutely no idea how to make it work - i tried several variations, and more and... nothing works :( - i Thinked that should be easy but... looks like a noob like me can't do it - can someone hlp me with this?

Comment: Thanks cFreed - your input showed me the right Direction - question is solved.